# Can I rename an Xively stream ID

Tags: xively

Is there a way to rename a Xively stream ID.  Because my feeds were created in cosm, they just have IDs like 0, 1 etc.  But in Xively, it would make more sense for them to be named.  Can I change the stream ID in xively?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a new datastream and transfer the data, if that's necessary, then delete the old datastream. You will also need to reprogrammed your device that sends data to this feed. May be it's best to actually create a new development device instead of the legacy feed you have.